# How to find all the aliases within a given file system?

Tags: filesystem, alias

I would like to avoid any future problems with aliases (empty files created with the Finder, not to be confused with symbolic links) I might have used in the past and which may stay within the system.
I discovered a lot of problem with this type of file:

- to backup (with `rsync`)
- to migrate on another file system (with `cp` or `rsync`)
- to migrate on another system (with `rcp`, `scp` or `rsync`)…

Now I want either to get rid of all of them or at least to know the size of the risk I still have with the remaining ones.

---

How may I find all the alias type files within a given filesystem using command line (shell script) using for example:

- `mdfind`
- `find`

Comment: I edited my answer to include using `find`.

Comment: The symbolic links aren't any source of problem. My question is focused on the aliases.

Comment: If it's only aliases created in Finder then I'd just use `mdfind` as it is better suited to explicitly show aliases where `find` is not.  While `find` can use `-xattrname` with `com.apple.FinderInfo` or `com.apple.ResourceFork`, the two extended attributes given to an alias created in Finder, nonetheless there are many other files that have these same extended attributes thus making it difficult to differentiate between what's a alias or not using the `find` command.  I'm not saying there is no a way with `find`, just I don't know of one off the top of my head.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To find aliases with `mdfind`, in a Terminal:

`mdfind kMDItemKind="Alias"`

This will print a list of aliases with the fully qualified pathname.

Note:  These are aliases created in Finder, not symbolic links created with the `ln` command from a Terminal or script.

To use `find` to find symbolic links created by, as an example, `ln` have a look at: `man find`

Example: `find / -type l`

This will start in the *root* of the Macintosh HD and traverse the entire filesystem that you have permission to read and output all symbolic links created by, as an example, `ln` showing the fully qualified pathname.

To augment the basic command example read `man find`.