# How can I find out which file(s) links to another file

Tags: terminal, symlink, alias

This is a question about the reverse of a file link, which I can easily see in either Terminal or Get Info, ie. this

```
lrwxr-xr-x   1 Alex  admin        35  7 Aug 23:35 envsubst -> ../Cellar/gettext/0.21/bin/envsubst
```

Is there a way to see which files link **to** another file without doing a recursive find across all volumes?

---

**EDIT 1:** (an extension to my original question, but not a good way to ask a second question)

Given the different nature of macOS aliases, is there is a way to find their original file too?

**EDIT 2:**
Answer to how to find aliases is [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182980/how-to-find-all-the-aliases-within-a-given-file-system).
In a nutshell: `mdfind kMDItemKind="Alias" | grep filename`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbolic links are just an entry in the currenct directory, as any other file. So if you want to find all symbolic links, you need to run `find / -type l -ls` or similar.

The link target (`../Cellar/gettext/0.21/bin/envsubst`) has no way of knowing which symbolic links points to it so there is no easy way to go "backwards".

You could run `find / -type l -ls > /tmp/symlinks` and then analyze the result to find link targets.

PS: StackOverflow has more on this: [Find all symlinks of a given 'original' file? (reverse 'readlink')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532241/linux-find-all-symlinks-of-a-given-original-file-reverse-readlink)

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4535344/1187415